# Redirect Apache application to dot net core application

Tags: apache, .net-core, webserver

I have a server which uses a domain example.com. I am using apache to run this web server. I have also installed Dot Net core and published a Dot Net core app to /var/www/app location.

I a trying to access this application using example.com/api

This below is what I have tried in 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin root@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

the below is what I hvae added for the application
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName example.com/api
       ProxyPreserveHost On

       <Proxy *>
               Order allow, deny
               Allow from all
       </Proxy>
       ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/
       ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/
</VirtualHost>
```

I have also tried the below configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName example.com/api
       redirect / http://localhost:5000/
</VirtualHost>
```

can someone please help me find what am I doing wrong and how to achieve this properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved by enabling proxy and proxy_http using commands below.

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
```

Also configured the Proxy inside the virtual host as follows.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin root@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    #Below 3 lines worked
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    Proxypass "/api/" "http://localhost:5000/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/api/" "http://localhost:5000/"

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```